# SFDC Enduser requests always go to Database?

Tags: architecture

Each interaction between and end user and the Apex runtime server requires a request to a Force.com database--is this correct..I thought it is because everything is stored as meta data
in database ,and you cannot bypass it.

Can architecture experts shed some light?

Is it same for Visualforce as well

(Its for self study purpose)

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce's Architect Core Resources would be your best learning material on this topic.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Architect_Core_Resources

Understanding the multi-tenant architecture may be a good starting point.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Multi_Tenant_Architecture